# What's our official position on fictional physics?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-faq

It seems to have become de facto policy that questions about fictional physics are off topic, unless they're sufficiently precisely written. I recently realized that wasn't mentioned in our [FAQ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) so I added the following blurb:

> **Questions about physics of fictional worlds**
>   *"Could warp drive get you out of a black hole?"*
>   Most questions about fictional physics are not addressed by existing theories or experiments, so we do not have the ability to answer them by applying physical laws. If your question falls under this category, it may be on topic at [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com).
>   *Exception:* if a question is formulated specifically enough in terms of modifications to existing theories, it may be okay.

Should we keep this, delete it, rewrite it, etc.?

Comment: To me this still looks fine, if there are corresponding theoretical ideas seriously persued by serious physicists it belongs here, if not it is rather science fiction.

Comment: fine , any way most of this type of questions are badly formulated and should be closed, so the FAQ warning is fair.

Comment: There are some shows -- *Gunbuster!* comes to mind, and *Futurama* -- where the show writers, creators, and producers made an effort to use as realistic physics as they could. Food for thought, really.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/863/2451 and links therein.